# Evaluate an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is Exercise 7.14.7 in  *Linear Operator Theory in Engineering and Science*:
$$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\pi^{-1/2}\exp{(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2})\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2}dt\int_{y}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt} , &\text{for $x\le y$}\\
\pi^{-1/2}\exp{(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2})\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-t^2}dt\int_{x}^\infty e^{-t^2}dt}, & \text{for $y<x$}
\end{cases}$$

Show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g(x,y)|^2dxdy=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} (\approx 2.2337)$$

I have used the numerical integration function of Mathematica 10.2 to calculate its value, it's about 0.4, far less then 2.2337. 
[image]